# How can I install Arch Linux on Mac? On an external hard drive?

Tags: osx, dual-boot

How can I install Arch onto a Macbook Air 2014? I'd also like this to be on an External Hard drive. I know how to boot into the BIOS and everything, I just feel like none of the guides have helped me. None of the have worked and I feel like there are extra steps I should take.

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. What guides have you followed? What steps have you taken? How does it fail?

Comment: I've followed about 6 or 7 youtube guides. I tried the Beginner's guide on the wiki. Every time I do it, if gives me a message like this: [root@root] #            And it won't let me type

Answer (score 0):

The [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MacBook#Installation) has a page just for installing Arch on a MacBook. In there, someone reported that:

> Some MacBook users report strange keyboard output such as long delays
>   and character doubling. To fix this problem, boot with the following
>   options: **`arch noapic irqpoll acpi=force`**